# SaltStack : Identify environment with DNS record

Tags: salt-stack

I have multiple isolated environments to setup with SaltStack. I have created some base states and custom states for each environment. For the moment, the only way I can identify an environment is by requesting a TXT record on the DNS server.
Is there a way I can select the right environment in SaltStack.
How can I put this information in a pillar or a grain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt's [`dig` module](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dig.html) might help you here. You can use it to query information from DNS records. It needs the command line dig tool to be installed.

Use a command line:

```
salt-call dig.TXT google.com
```

to produce an output like this:

```
local:
    - "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Use a salt state to put it into a grain:

```
# setupgrain.sls
mygrainname:
  grains.present:
    - value: {{ salt['dig.TXT']('google.com') }}
```

Once you have the information in a grain you can [select salt nodes on the grain information using matchers](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html).